# In wheel theory, does $1/0$ have a one-to-one mapping to any set? Or is the concept of a one-to-one mapping outside of its definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinity, wheel-theory

As I understand it, infinities typically have a one-to-one mapping with known sets. The denumerable infinity has a one-to-one mapping with integers, rational numbers, and natural numbers.  The nondenumerable infinity has a one-to-one mapping to the set of real numbers and the power set of the integers.

Is there any such set that maps to $1/0$ in wheel theory? It's definition appears to be a type of infinity.  Am I correct about this or is my assumption outside the standard definitions used in wheel theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking of $\mathbb R$ as an affine line, one can complete it to a real projective line $\mathbb R P^1$ by adding an "ideal point at infinity" sometimes denoted $\infty$.  Similarly, viewing $\mathbb C$ as an affine complex line, one adds a point at infinity to form the complex projective line $\mathbb C P^1$.  These are examples of wheels in [wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) where one similarly adds points at infinity.  Such a notion of a point at infinity has nothing to do with Cantorian infinite cardinals, whether denumerable or non-denumerable.